# Array en React para importar mas de un bloque

Tags: reactjs

estoy haciendo para mostrar un bloque de codigo en `React`, la idea es poder hacerlo todo desde el mismo archivo, un ejemplo, de lo que tengo y lo que necesito:

```
if (i === 3) {//Bloque que quiero importar
  lis.push(<Btn />);
}
```

`Codigo que importo:`

```
const Btn = () => {//Este bloque de 3 botones es para i === 3
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" href={arg[0]}>
        ABRIR
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" href={arg[1]}>
        ABRIR
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" href={arg[2]}>
        ABRIR
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Ahora el problema, si en el codigo que importo, quiero agregar otro bloque con otra configuracion, pero para mostrar POR EJEMPLO: si para `i === 4` quiero importar esto:

```
if (i === 4) {//Bloque que quiero importar
  lis.push(<Btn />);
}
```

`Codigo que importo:`

```
const Btn = () => {// Este bloque de 3 botones seria para i === 4
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" href={esp[0]}>
        ABRIR
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" href={esp[1]}>
        ABRIR
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" href={esp[2]}>
        ABRIR
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Ahora deberia hayar la forma de juntar los dos bloques en un mismo archivo, y llamar a cada bloque cuando lo necesite. Como puedo hacer, pense en un array, pero no encontre una forma precisa.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes parametrizar tu componente por medio de un `prop`, esto es una propiedad que quieres heredar a tu componente, en este caso vamos a heredar una propiedad llamada `variant` que especifica si es `outlined` o`contained` y la pasas a los hijos que habitan dentor del componente:

```
const Btn = ({variant}) => {// Este bloque de 3 botones seria para i === 4
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Button variant={variant} color="primary" href={esp[0]}>
        ABRIR
      </Button>
      <Button variant={variant} color="primary" href={esp[1]}>
        ABRIR
      </Button>
      <Button variant={variant} color="primary" href={esp[2]}>
        ABRIR
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Para este caso use destructuring del `prop`, luego cuando vas a usar tu componente en tu condicional puedes hacer cosas como:

```
if (i === 4) {//Bloque que quiero importar
  lis.push(<Btn variant="outlined" />);
}
```

O:

```
if (i === 3) {//Bloque que quiero importar
  lis.push(<Btn variant="contained" />);
}
```

Comment: Claro, igualmente eso lo cambie para que se vea que no es el mismo codigo, ya que la idea es que eso no cambie.

Comment: ¿Esto da una respuesta a tu pregunta? De lo contrario no te estoy entendiendo, si lo logro podría darte una solución diferente.

Comment: Si responderia, pero la idea es que esa `variant` sea la misma.

Comment: Lo que si cambia es el `href`, no se si se puede utilizar eso para poder llamar a cada bloque.

Comment: No logro seguirte, más sencillo. ¿Cuál código es el que quieres que quede igual? ¿Dónde haces el condicional o el del componente?

Comment: Puedes usar la referencia, pero tendrías que guardarla como un estado en el componente padre, podrías guardar la referencia de `<Btn/>` y luego editar sus propiedades por medio de la misma.

Comment: Ahi edite la pregunta, explicando un poco mejor

Comment: no entiendo, creo que lo que dices igual no es lo que necesito

Comment: Es que no comprendo. ¿Quieres hacer como un tipo de importación condicional?  En la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) de `import` vienen casos para hacer una importación condicional.

Comment: quiero poder utilizar distintos bloques, `<Btn [0] />` y aparezca un boton y si pongo `<btn [1] />` aparezca otro boton, pero no quiero crear 15mil archivos con todos los botones, quiero usar el mismo archivo... Se entiende?

Comment: ¿Y cual es la diferencia entre `Btn[0]` y `Btn[1]|` ?  Tu ya puedes reutilizar componentes de React.

Comment: era un ejemplo visual...